# Iphone Distribution AppStore Provisioning

Tags: objective-c, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect, provisioning

A customer requested the development of an IOS application, and I've started the development with my apple developer account. I release some Ad-Hoc distribution for validation and the client eventually liked the result and decided to publish in the AppStore in his account.

The client gave me access to his account developer that I would generate the distribution provisioning and publish in ItunesConnect.

The client has two other applications, which are awaiting approval from Apple, which were published by another developer. My problem is that even creating my distribution provisioning, when I download and add to the XCode shows the message "profile does not match any valid certificate / private key pair in the default keychain."
I downloaded the distribution certificate that already existed in the account.

What should I do to fix this problem?

Many thanks,

Andre

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need the private key used to sign that profile (the .p12 file is used for interchange).  Hopefully your client has it.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response.
He must have passed this file to the other developer, since he managed to publish?

Comment: Or the other dev created it.  This has been a huge PIA in contract work that I've done where other devs were involved first.  Best of luck.  Hotpaw's answer below mine is probably your second step if you can't get a hold of the original keys, though you don't need the 2nd paragraph about multiple mac accounts.  I've never had a conflict with multiple dev keypairs on my system.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to revoke and recreate the clients Distribution certificate, since it is unlikely they have their private keys if they didn't create their current certificates.

You might also consider downloading the clients certificates into a separate Mac User account, and building and signing their app using that account, so you don't mix multiple certificates into the Keychain in your own Mac user account.